# Apply over rows of data.table: find rows where a subset of columns are all NA

Tags: r, data.table, apply, na

I am trying, in my quest to rewrite old (slow) code with the `data.table` package, to figure out the best way to use `apply` with a data.table.

I have a data.table with multiple id columns, then multiple columns that have dose-response data in a wide format. I need to generalize the answer because not all data.tables will have the same number of dose-response columns. For simplicity I think the following data.table addresses the issue:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1234)
DT1 =  data.table(unique_id = paste0('id',1:1e6),
                 dose1 = sample(c(1:9,NA),1e6,replace=TRUE),
                 dose2 = sample(c(1:9,NA),1e6,replace=TRUE)
                 )

> DT1
          unique_id dose1 dose2
       1:       id1     2     2
       2:       id2     7     4
       3:       id3     7     9
       4:       id4     7     4
       5:       id5     9     3
---                      
  999996:  id999996     4     3
  999997:  id999997    NA     3
  999998:  id999998     4     2
  999999:  id999999     8     5
 1000000: id1000000     6     7
```

So each row has a unique id, some other ids, and I have left out the response columns, because they will be `NA` where the dose columns are `NA`. What I need to do is remove rows where all of the dose columns are `NA`. I came up with the first option, then realized I could trim it down to the second option.

```
DT2 <- copy(DT1)
DT3 <- copy(DT1)

len.not.na <- function(x){length(which(!is.na(x)))}

option1 <- function(DT){
  DT[,flag := apply(.SD,1,len.not.na),.SDcols=grep("dose",colnames(DT))]
  DT <- DT[flag != 0]
  DT[ , flag := NULL ]
}

option2 <- function(DT){
  DT[ apply(DT[,grep("dose",colnames(DT)),with=FALSE],1,len.not.na) != 0 ]
}

> microbenchmark(op1 <- option1(DT2), op2 <- option2(DT3),times=25L)
Unit: seconds
                expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 op1 <- option1(DT2) 8.364504 8.863436 9.145341 11.27827 11.50356    25
 op2 <- option2(DT3) 8.291549 8.774746 8.982536 11.15269 11.72199    25
```

Clearly they two options do about the same thing, with option 1 having a few more steps, but I wanted to test how calling `.SD` might slow things down as has been suggested by other posts ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16865506/1623354)).

Either way both options are still on the slow side. Any suggestions to speeding things up?

**EDIT with comment from @AnandaMahto**

```
DT4 <- copy(DT1)
option3 <- function(DT){
  DT[rowSums(DT[,grep("dose",colnames(DT)),with=FALSE]) != 0]
}

> microbenchmark(op2 <- option2(DT3), op3 <- option3(DT4),times=5L)
Unit: milliseconds
               expr        min         lq    median        uq       max neval
op2 <- option2(DT3) 7738.21094 7810.87777 7838.6067 7969.5543 8407.4069     5
op3 <- option3(DT4)   83.78921   92.65472  320.6273  559.8153  783.0742     5
```

`rowSums` is definitely faster. I am happy with the solution unless anyone has something faster.

Comment: Did you try `rowSums`?

Comment: You might find this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646172/select-na-in-a-data-table-in-r) helpful -

Comment: `DT1[!is.na(dose1) | !is.na(dose2)]` ?

Comment: This will also work but should be &

Comment: @AnandaMahto I had not thought of that. It's quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My approach would be as follows:

Use `rowSums` to find the rows you want to keep:

```
Dose <- grep("dose", colnames(DT1))
# .. menas "up one level
Flag <- rowSums(is.na(DT1[, ..Dose])) != length(Dose)
DT1[Flag]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DT1[!is.na(dose1) | !is.na(dose2)]
```

The `Reduce` generalization in previous edits was wrong, here's the correct version:

```
DT1[(!Reduce("*", DT1[, lapply(.SD, is.na), .SDcols = patterns("dose")]))]
```

**Benchmarks**

```
rowsum = function(dt) {
  Dose <- grep("dose", colnames(dt))
  Flag <- rowSums(is.na(dt[, ..Dose])) != length(Dose)
  dt[Flag]
}

reduce = function(dt) {
  dt[(!Reduce("*", dt[, lapply(.SD, is.na), .SDcols = patterns("dose")]))]
}

# original data
microbenchmark(rowsum(copy(DT1)), reduce(copy(DT1)), times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#              expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# rowsum(copy(DT1)) 184.4121 190.9895 238.2935 248.0654 266.5708    10
# reduce(copy(DT1)) 141.2399 172.2020 199.1012 219.4567 424.1526    10

# a lot more columns
for (i in 10:100) DT1[, paste0('dose', i) := sample(c(NA, 1:10), 1e6, T)]

microbenchmark(rowsum(copy(DT1)), reduce(copy(DT1)), times = 10)
#Unit: seconds
#              expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# rowsum(copy(DT1)) 4.160035 4.428527 4.505705 4.754398 4.906849    10
# reduce(copy(DT1)) 3.421675 4.172700 4.507304 4.622355 5.156840    10
```

So at 100 columns `Reduce` still does all right.

Comment: That's essentially looping in R (with `Reduce`), which is not really necessary, while we could use vectorised functions.

Comment: yep, it's looping over the columns (and is vectorized for each column)

Comment: Yes, but we could do better than that - vectorised over all columns :). `Reduce` doesn't scale well.

Comment: I do not really understand how this works, but it seems to be faster than the `rowSums` option - see my edit. @Arun Can you give an example of how to remove the `Reduce`?

Comment: As long as you've only a few columns, it doesn't matter if you use `Reduce` or not.

Comment: @Arun I realized that after I made the edit. I reran the comparison with 40 dose columns and this method was still faster than `rowSums` - albeit much harder to understand.

Comment: @Arun all right, I don't think you're wrong - it does start losing once you have more than 100 or so columns

Comment: @Arun - actually turns out that was an anomalous measurement - I don't have enough patience to see at what point reduce would lose (if ever) - it's still doing just fine at 100 columns

Comment: @eddi I am still having a really hard time understanding how `Reduce` works here. Can you clarify a little for my benefit?

Comment: @dayne `Reduce` is a way of stringing together repetitive expressions - if you want to e.g. do `x1+x2+x3+x4+...` you can do this by adding two elements at a time like so: `((((x1 + x2) + x3) + x4) + ...)` and `Reduce` formalizes this as: `Reduce(function(x, y) x + y, list(x1,x2,x3,...))`. Since `data.table` is a list, that's what I did above for a slightly more complicated function than just `+`.

Comment: @eddi I expected `Reduce(function(x, y) is.na(x) * is.na(y), rep(NA,5))` to return 1... but it does not. However, `Reduce("*",is.na(rep(NA,5)))` behaves like I expect. I'm just super confused.

Comment: @dayne that's because I made a mistake in the reduce expression :) - let me see if I can correct it

Comment: @eddi Interesting. It seems to work as is, despite the mistake.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41486/discussion-between-dayne-and-eddi)

Comment: @eddi, a few is at least 1000, I'd say. So, for columns it seems to me to be perfectly acceptable (at these data dimensions). If you want to test the performance create a list with say 1e3,1e4,1e5 rows (with random number of elements in each) and do an operation (and try the non-reduce way of accomplishing it). I'm trying to find a post where I benchmarked `reduce`.. I'll link it if I manage to find it. In my benchmarking, even at 100, the median times gets bigger than `rowSums`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe easier to just select all the rows with no NAs into a new table like this. You can  amend the 'which' condition depending on your table:

```
DT2<-(DT1[which(!is.na(DT1$dose1) & !is.na(DT1$dose2)),])
```