# How to create mean and s.d. columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, mean, calculated-columns

The following code/outcome baffles me as to why data.table returns NA for the mean functions and not the sd function.

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.frame('id'=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   'A'=seq(2,9,length=5),
                   'B'=seq(3,9,length=5),
                   'C'=seq(4,9,length=5),
                   'D'=seq(5,9,length=5))

test <- as.data.table(test)

test[,`:=`(mean_test = mean(.SD), sd_test = sd(.SD)),by=id,.SDcols=c('A','B','C','D')]
> test
   id    A   B    C    D mean_test   sd_test
   1:  1 2.00 3.0 4.00 5        NA 1.2909944
   2:  2 3.75 4.5 5.25 6        NA 0.9682458
   3:  3 5.50 6.0 6.50 7        NA 0.6454972
   4:  4 7.25 7.5 7.75 8        NA 0.3227486
   5:  5 9.00 9.0 9.00 9        NA 0.0000000
```

I've learned quite a bit searching around, going through the DT tutorials/examples.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860200/row-by-row-operations-and-updates-in-data-table) question is very similar to what I was hoping to do.

Why does the standard deviation function work and the mean function return NA?

**Edit**: Using Ricardo Saporta's solution:

```
test[,`:=`(mean_test = apply(.SD, 1, mean), sd_test = apply(.SD, 1, sd),by=id,.SDcols=c('A','B','C','D')]

> test
   id    A   B    C D mean_test   sd_test
1:  1 2.00 3.0 4.00 5     3.500 1.2909944
2:  2 3.75 4.5 5.25 6     4.875 0.9682458
3:  3 5.50 6.0 6.50 7     6.250 0.6454972
4:  4 7.25 7.5 7.75 8     7.625 0.3227486
5:  5 9.00 9.0 9.00 9     9.000 0.0000000
```

Comment: there is no need for `test <- test[, \`:=\` .... ` - In fact, the whole point of the `:=` operator is to avoid this re-assigning  ;)

Comment: Thanks, I made the update.  Still running into a problem though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.SD` is itself a `data.table`
Thus, when you take `mean(.SD)` you are (attempting) to take the mean of an entire data.table

The function `mean()` does not know what to do with the data.table and returns `NA`

#### Have a look

```
## the .SD in your question is the same as 
test[, c('A','B','C','D')]

## try taking its mean
mean(test[, c('A','B','C','D')])

# Warning in mean.default(test[, c("A", "B", "C", "D")]) :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# [1] NA
```

#### try this instead

use `lapply(.SD, mean)`  for column-wise 
 or  `apply(.SD, 1, mean)` for row-wise

Answer (score 10):

You can make `mean` work by using `rowMeans` instead, and thus avoid using `apply` (similar to the linked question)

```
test[,`:=`(mean_test = rowMeans(.SD), 
           sd_test = sd(.SD)),
     by=id,.SDcols=c('A','B','C','D')]
test
#    id    A   B    C D mean_test   sd_test
# 1:  1 2.00 3.0 4.00 5     3.500 1.2909944
# 2:  2 3.75 4.5 5.25 6     4.875 0.9682458
# 3:  3 5.50 6.0 6.50 7     6.250 0.6454972
# 4:  4 7.25 7.5 7.75 8     7.625 0.3227486
# 5:  5 9.00 9.0 9.00 9     9.000 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather as a fun fact, one can use a vector of columns in `mean()` and `sd()`:

```
test[, `:=` (mean = mean(c(A,B,C,D)),
             sd   = sd(c(A,B,C,D))),  by=id]
test
#    id    A   B    C D   mean        sd
# 1:  1 2.00 3.0 4.00 5  3.500 1.2909944
# 2:  2 3.75 4.5 5.25 6  4.875 0.9682458
# 3:  3 5.50 6.0 6.50 7  6.250 0.6454972
# 4:  4 7.25 7.5 7.75 8  7.625 0.3227486
# 5:  5 9.00 9.0 9.00 9  9.000 0.0000000
```

And you can also use `quote()` and `eval()`:

```
cols <- quote(c(A,B,C,D))
test[, ':=' (mean = mean(eval(cols)), 
             sd  = sd(eval(cols))),  by=id]
```

Comment: Though you will need to also do `by=id` which is vasically doing a by-row operations.