# How to create means and s.d. columns with data.table (based on multiple conditions)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have been able to create a table with the `median` `mean` and `sd`, based on several conditions, using the `dplry` package. To do so I prepped the data. It looks a bit sloppy to me and I am using a big dataset (>3gb) so I have been using `data.table` already.

**I am wondering how I can create a similar table more efficiently using the `data.table` package**, so, if it is possible to do this without prepping the data too much. That would be great as I need to do this for many other conditions as well. Btw, I checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535573/how-to-create-mean-and-s-d-columns-in-data-table?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it didn't add conditions.

**This is what I have and need:**

I need the `mean` of `con` by `id` and `date`= 1 year since first `i` or `i2` = `A04` or `A01`.

EDIT (because it wasn't running before):

**DATA:**

```
DT <- structure(list(id = c(123L, 123L, 332L, 332L, 332L, 100L, 100L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 551L, 551L), 
               i = c("D95", "F85", "A01", "A04", "K20", "B10", "A04", "T08", "P28", "D95", "A04", "B12", "D95"), 
               i2 = c("F15", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "A01", "", "A01", ""), 
               date = c("2015-06-19", "2016-08-15", "2013-03-16", "2017-01-17", "2013-01-16", "2009-05-08", "2011-04-03", "2015-05-04",
                        "2011-04-04", "2017-08-04", "2011-05-24", "2013-11-04", "2013-05-04"), 
               con = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",  "1", "1", "1"), 
               PS = c("0",  "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0")), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

**The following is what I have done so far (and which works):**

I created the columns `PS` (= having either `A01` or `A04` in `i` or `i2`) and `ds`(=days since first `A01` or `A01` (days aren't correct here)) based on the data.

With the `dplyr` package I first made a `data.table` with only rows with only `ds` between -365&0.

```
j.ds <- subset(DT, ds >= -365 & ds < 0)
```

Than agregated to a table with `sum` of `con` per `id`, like so:

```
j <- j.ds %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(con = sum(con))
```

From there I made the desired table:

```
jP <- j %>%
  summarise(median = median(con), mean = mean(con), SD = sd(con))
```

Comment: Please check your example data, there seems to be a mistake

Comment: Sorry, it should run now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell you want the sum of `con` per `id`, for data where `ds` is between -365 and 0, then the mean, median and standard deviation of those sums. This can be done by chaining two expressions.

```
DT[ds >= -365 & ds < 0, sum(con), by = "id"][, .(mean(V1), median(V1), sd(V1))]
```

This first subsets your data, then sums `con` per `id`, then takes the mean etc. of the sums with a second expression

Comment: Thank you, but I get the following error `Error in gsum(con) : 
  Type 'character' not supported by GForce sum (gsum). Either add the prefix base::sum(.) or turn off GForce optimization using options(datatable.optimize=1)`

Comment: You have con as a character, use `as.numeric(con)` or convert it in the data

Comment: Okay, so no shortcuts there ;) It seems to work on the test set `DT`, thanks. Going to try it on my larger set.
Do you also have solution to getting these results from a dataset that doesn't contain the columns `PS` `ds` and `con` (yet)?

Comment: Also, if con is always 1, you could use .N, rather than sum(con), though you would need to change the mean(V1) to be mean(N) etc. Also if this answers your question please accept/upvote :)

Comment: As an example, using the iris dataset... `DT <- data.table(iris);
DT[Petal.Length > 1 & Petal.Length < 5, .N, by = "Species"][, .(mean(N), sd(N))]`

Comment: It all works! Changing to using `.N` works, although when I changed mean(V1) etc. to mean(N) it gave the overall frequency (I think). Back to mean(V1) gave me the desired result. Thank you so much and could you also upvote my question so I can finally get rights to comment in other posts instead of making StackOverflow more cluttered with questions related to existing posts?

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot run your example, I give you an untested `data.table` translation of your `dplyr` code.

You can do the operations you were doing quite efficiently in `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(jx)
j <- jx[ds >= -365 & ds < 0, lapply(.SD, sum), by = "id"]
jP <- j[, lapply(.SD, function(x) return(c(median(x), mean(x), sd(x)))]
jP[,'stat' := c("median","mean","sd")
```

You end-up with a long formatted dataframe.

## Edit

If you have non-numeric columns, you must not sum them. You can control the columns used in `.SD` with `.SDcols`. For instance, in your example, the columns are character: to do a sum you need to convert them to numeric. For instance, if you are interested in `con` and `PS` columns, you should do:

```r
cols <- c("con","PS")
j <- DT[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x))), by = "id", .SDcols = cols]
```

With `function(x) sum(as.numeric(x))` you create an anonymous function (equivalent to `lambda` functions in `python` that applies as.numeric and sum all elements in your `subset of data` (SD).

The anonymous function  `return(c(median(x), mean(x), sd(x)))` follows the same logic

Comment: The 3rd line gives the following error: `Error in gsum(i) : 
  Type 'character' not supported by GForce sum (gsum). Either add the prefix base::sum(.) or turn off GForce optimization using options(datatable.optimize=1)`
And I've edited my dataset, sorry about that!
Can you also explain what the x in function(x) means? I've seen it elsewhere but don't understand where it comes from.

Comment: You were summing over character variables. See my edit

Comment: I also answer your question regarding the `function(x)` notation

Comment: I've run:
  `cols <- c("con","PS", 'ds', 'id', 'i', 'i2')
    j <- DT[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x))), by = "id", .SDcols = cols]
    j <- DT[ds >= -365 & ds < 0, lapply(.SD, sum), by = "id"]`
And still get the error:
`Error in sum(i) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument`
Also tried after dropping the `i` and `i2` columns, but still similar error. Luckily rg255's sollution works. Thanks, also for the rest of the explanations, that clears things up for my beginner brain.

Comment: You're welcome. The error comes from the fact that you no longer need `j <- DT[ds >= -365 & ds < 0, lapply(.SD, sum), by = "id"]` since you already aggregated with `j <- DT[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x))), by = "id", .SDcols = cols] `.